# Tools for proving map is homotopy equivalence

Tags: homotopy-theory

**General situation**

I'm preparing a geometry exam, and a lot of exercises from past years' exams are of the form «given $f$ the map so-and-so, prove (or determine whether) it is a homotopy equivalence». Most of the time, I'm pretty at a loss.

**One possible trick (correct?)**

Either the arrival space is contractible, from which I conclude any map from it to itself is homotopic to every other one (is that correct?), so I just need a putative homotopic inverse which is usually not too hard to find, or I start trying to think without too much success.

**Another tool to be proved valid**

One thing I would like to prove is that if two maps are homotopic, their images must have the same number of connected components. Suppose $f,g:X\to X$ are continuous and homotopic, i.e. there is $H:X\times[0,1]\to X$ a continuous map such that $H(x,0)=f(x),H(x,1)=g(x)$ for all $x\in X$. Suppose $f(X)$ is connected and $g(X)$ isn't. If I prove this leads to a contradiction, I will have proved my claim, since if $f(X)$ has $n$ connected components and $g(X)$ has $m<n$, I can restrict myself to the preimage of one connected component of $g(X)$ such that the image of that under $f$ is not connected, which must exist, and reapply the reasoning to their restrictions, which must still be homotopic. And anyway for now I have only needed this less general version. But how do I prove it? Let $x,y\in X$. Suppose $f(x),f(y)$ are in different connected components, whereas $g(x),g(y)$ are in the same. In particular, in the same pathwise connected component. I therefore have a curve from $g(x)$ to $g(y)$, let it be $\gamma$. This, I fear, won't bring me anywhere, as I can't make $\gamma$ "talk" with $f$ in anyway. Maybe we can try to restrict $H$ to the curve $\gamma$, but we'd have to bring it back to $X$ through a probably nonexistent inverse of $g$. Or maybe we can consider $K:[0,1]^2\to X$ defined as $K(t,s)=H(\gamma(t),s)$. But I can't see any use of this. Is my claim true? How do I prove it?

**General question**

Is there any theorem that could be of help, i.e. any theorem saying «if so-and-so, then the map is a homotopy equivalence»?

**Particular case**

In particular, I'm dealing with $V=\mathbb{CP}^2\smallsetminus\{X=0\}$, the projective complex plane being parametrized by $[X:Y:Z]$, and $\pi:V\to\mathbb{CP}^1$ the projection on the last two components $\pi([X:Y:Z])=(Y:Z)$. I have found a possible homotopy inverse $g([Y:Z])=[1:Y:Z]$. This is indeed a homotopy equivalence, and a homeomorphism with inverse $g^{-1}([X:Y:Z])=[\frac{Y}{X}:\frac{Z}{X}]$. $f\circ g([Y:Z])$ is clearly the identity. The other composition is $[X:Y:Z]\mapsto[1:Y:Z]$. How do I prove this is homotopic to the identity of $\mathbb{CP}^2$?

Comment: I am also preparing for such an exam, is it possible for you share the source of the questions you used?

Comment: The source should be [this one](http://peano.matapp.unimib.it/~conti/). Note: everything there is in Italian. For the record, I took the written exam at the end of April and the oral halfway through May, got 23 in the written part and took it up to 29 with the oral. If only I had read those "$z=0$" which made cylinders into circles! I would then have gotten more points in writing and perhaps a final 30.